# Oracle 11g Pmml import

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c, pmml

I am using oracle data miner for making some calculations. I need register pmml file to execute my calculations.

I have two oracle databases. First oracle database version is 12c. After installed oracle data miner I am using the code below for register my pmml.

```
ALTER SESSION set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ".," 

BEGIN    
   dbms_data_mining.IMPORT_MODEL ('PMML_SAO_PD_AL01',
        XMLType (bfilename ('EXT_TAB_DIR_ADM_TEST', 'PMML_SAO_PD_AL01.xml'),
          nls_charset_id ('AL32UTF8')
        ));
END;
```

That code works perfectly in oracle 12c.

My second database version is 11g. After installed oracle data miner, when I run the same code, it gets the error below

> ORA-40388: Unsupported feature in PMML document: Output

Cause of some licence restrictions, it is not possible to upgrade my oracle 11g db version to 12c.

My pmml code (PMML_SAO_PD_AL01.xml) is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <PMML version="4.2"   xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Header copyright="Copyright(c) Garanti Bank">
<Application name="GT - PMML Generator Addin" version="1.0"/>
<Timestamp>2016-11-15 08:56:21</Timestamp>
</Header>
<DataDictionary numberOfFields="2">
<DataField name="TARGET_NUM" optype="categorical" dataType="string"/>
<DataField name="RAW_SCORE" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
</DataDictionary>
<TransformationDictionary>
</TransformationDictionary>
<RegressionModel functionName="classification" targetFieldName="TARGET_NUM" normalizationMethod="">
<MiningSchema>
<MiningField name="TARGET_NUM" usageType="target" optype="categorical"/>
<MiningField name="RAW_SCORE" usageType="active" optype="continuous"/>
</MiningSchema>
<Output>
<OutputField name="I_TARGET_NUM" displayName="Into: TARGET_NUM" optype="categorical" dataType="string" targetField="TARGET_NUM" feature="predictedValue"/>
<OutputField name="U_TARGET_NUM" displayName="Unnormalized Into: TARGET_NUM" optype="categorical" dataType="string" targetField="TARGET_NUM" feature="predictedDisplayValue"/>
<OutputField name="P_TARGET_NUM1" displayName="Predicted: TARGET_NUM=1" optype="continuous" dataType="double" targetField="TARGET_NUM" feature="probability" value="1"/>
<OutputField name="P_TARGET_NUM0" displayName="Predicted: TARGET_NUM=0" optype="continuous" dataType="double" targetField="TARGET_NUM" feature="probability" value="0"/>
</Output>
<Targets>
<Target  field="TARGET_NUM" optype="categorical">
<TargetValue value="1" displayValue="1" priorProbability="0.5"/>
<TargetValue value="0" displayValue="0" priorProbability="0.5"/>
</Target>
</Targets>
<LocalTransformations>
</LocalTransformations>
<RegressionTable intercept="-0.045" targetCategory="1">
<NumericPredictor name="RAW_SCORE" coefficient="0.97"/>
</RegressionTable>
<RegressionTable intercept="0" targetCategory="0"/>
</RegressionModel>
</PMML>
```

Now, I examined and compared that db's configurations but i didn't find sth that makes that difference. So I suppose that 11g doesn't support that version of pmml. But actually I need use output field tags which cause of error.

How can I register my pmml to oracle 11g? Or is there any possible way like make some changes in pmml for making it suitable for oracle 11g?

Comment: any idea? @user1808924

Comment: That's a question for Oracle technical support. I would recommend you to temporarily remove parts of your PMML document in order to see what PMML features are supported/unsupported in 11g. For starters, completely remove the `/PMML/RegressionModel/Output` and see if the import works or not. If it works, then add it back and repeat the exclusion process with individual `OutputField` elements.